# Parsing large decimals numbers in Javascript cause precision lost

Tags: javascript, rounding, largenumber

When parsing large decimal numbers, javascript arbitrary rounds and loses some decimal places.

With a 'small' number, everything happens as expected:

```
var str = '1.1234567899'; -> undefined
console.log( Number(str) ); -> 1.1234567899
```

With a 'large' number, it's rounded and some data are lost:

```
var str = '123456789.1234567899'; -> undefined
console.log( Number(str) ); -> 123456789.12345679
```

Notice the diff between input and output:
**123456789.1234567**899 !== **123456789.1234567**9

I'm trying to understand why it happens. Anyone?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: Solution: Take a look in bignumber Math.js -> http://mathjs.org/examples/bignumbers.js.html

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have an integer value, any number is internally stored as double. So if the value goes to large it will lose some precision.

The `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` constant represents the maximum safe integer in JavaScript (2^53 - 1).